# Select observations in dataframe based on a mask

Tags: r, dataframe

How do I select observations in a dataframe based on another dataframe that specifies a mask?

E.g.

The original data:

```
> df
   V1 V2 V3 V4
1   3  3 10  5
2   4  2  3  6
3   6  7  7  5
```

The mask:

```
> mask_df
      V1    V2    V3    V4
1   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2   TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
3  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

The expected output:

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  3  3 10
2  4  3  6
3  7  7  5
```

Here's code for generating the original dataframe and the mask:

```
#specify rows
rows = 3

#create the original dataframe
df = data.frame(V1 = sample.int(10,size = rows,replace = TRUE), 
                V2 = sample.int(10,size = rows,replace = TRUE),
                V3 = sample.int(10,size = rows,replace = TRUE), 
                V4 = sample.int(10,size = rows,replace = TRUE))

#view df
df

#create the mask dataframe
mask_df = data.frame(V1 = logical(), V2 = logical(), V3 = logical(), V4= logical())

#fill in the mask
for(i in seq(1,rows))
{
  mask_df[i,] = sample( c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), 4, replace = FALSE)
}

#view the mask
mask_df

#attempt to pass mask to dataframe
reduced_df = df[mask_df]
```

**EDIT: The number of TRUE values is guaranteed to be 3 and the number of false guaranteed to be 1 **

Comment: Why do you have this need?  This looks like bad data design to me.

Comment: unfortunately I can't influence the way in which I receive the data

Comment: what would happen if the amount of FALSE is not equal to the number of rows ?

Comment: How did you get your expected output? It does not seem to be inline with your `mask_df`

Comment: He removes every value having `FALSE` in `mask_df` and shifts everything to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This reproduces your expected outcome, but I completely agree with @TimBiegeleisen; this appears to be an awful data design and operation.

```
ncol <- sum(df2[1, ] == TRUE);
matrix(unlist(t(df1))[unlist(t(df2))], ncol = ncol, byrow = T);
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    3    3   10
#[2,]    4    3    6
#[3,]    7    7    5
```

---

### Sample data

```
# Your numeric data
df1 <- read.table(text =
    "V1 V2 V3 V4
1   3  3 10  5
2   4  2  3  6
3   6  7  7  5", header = T)

# Your mask data
df2 <- read.table(text = 
    "V1    V2    V3    V4
1   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2   TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
3  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE", header = T)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why this is awful data design?

Comment: For example, the number of columns of your output seems to be determined by the number of `TRUE`s in the first row: 3 `TRUE`s in row 1 give an output matrix with 3 columns. Let me ask you: What happens if there is only one `TRUE` in your mask for row 1? How would the expected output look?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify that the number of true and false are always 3 and 1

Comment: Why not store rows as numeric vectors in a `list`?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea with a different output using `mapply`,

```
mapply(function(x, y) ifelse(y, x, NA), df, mask_df)
```

which gives,

> ```
>     V1 V2 V3 V4
> [1,]  4 10 NA  7
> [2,] NA  5  2  5
> [3,]  3 NA  3  2
> ```

**NOTE** The `mask_df` is different than yours because of `sample` function you used without seed

Comment: I like this use of `mapply` ! To get the expected output (remove `NA` and shift every rows to the right) you can use `apply` wich will do the trick `apply(result_mapply, 1L, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`

Comment: @JulienNavarre, I don't want to 'pollute" that with a rowwise `apply`.